# How to get images src but restrict access?

Tags: laravel

Users can upload files and these files are stored in `app/storage/uploads/`

Then I want to display the uploaded images in the browser as a grid of images

I am using the Fetch API to get the images (or AJAX)

So I created a symlink from `app/storage/uploads/` to `app/public/storage/uploads`.

But now everyone has access to all the images because they are publicly available.

What is the correct way to restrict access to these images then (So that every user can only view his uploaded files, or files that other users gave him permission to view)?

Edit: The uploaded images are randmoly stored in the `uploads` folder:

```
app/storage/uploads/a/image1.jpg
app/storage/uploads/b/c/image2.jpg
app/storage/uploads/d/e/f/image3.jpg
app/storage/uploads/z/image4.jpg
```

So there isn't any relation to the user's id.